# Serialize to canonical XML with Saxon

Tags: xml, saxon, canonicalization

Is it possible to configure Saxon's [Serializer](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Serializer.html) to produce [canonical XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n11)?

I found that by default it can produce markup that is not in line with the canonical XML; e.g., self-closing element tags. I checked the available [serialization properties](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Serializer.Property.html), but I haven't found any that seem relevant to canonicalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature will be present in Saxon 9.9 (via the Serialization extension property `saxon:canonical="yes"`) but I'm afraid you'll have to wait for it. In the meantime you have to put the output through a separate canonicalizer.